# real escape string whitelist

Tags: php

Whether text of paragraph is input and `<br>` tag will be remove after real_escape_string, how do I whitelist the break tag?

Comment: real_escape_string has nothing to do with `<br>` tag. Some other code does. strip_tags() may be. Why do you get any tags in this text? is it some trusted editor's input?

Comment: it will remove the tag unless I comment out.

Comment: is it called "real_escape_string" or mysql_real_escape_string()?

Comment: but Parametrized statements provide a more secure way of handle data?

Comment: no. mysql_real_escape_string() provide the same security but just harder to understand.  well it cannot be this function. you have to double-check. Just ensure you have your record added whan you comment the function out

Answer (score 0):

use strip_tag instead.  The second parameter is an array of allowed tags

php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 0):

I manage to use alternative method, nl2br then mysql_real_escape_string and finally use str_replace to allow `<br>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Is real_escape_string() a user defined function or are you referring to mysql_real_escape_string?

Because **mysql_real_escape_string()** will escape `"` to `\"` but will leave 
`<br>` alone.